# Check if app is launched/openend by a SharePlay session

Tags: swift, ios15

When a user is in a Facetime call and accepted the SharePlay request, I want to push a specific `ViewController`. So I thought it would be same as to get notification when the user tap "accept".

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
        
    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    
    
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            
            // to perform action when notification is tapped
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            
            registerForPushNotifications()
            
            return true
        }
    
     func registerForPushNotifications() {
               UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                   .requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
                       [weak self] granted, error in
                       
                       print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
                       guard granted else { return }
                       self?.getNotificationSettings()
               }
           }
           
           func getNotificationSettings() {
               UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
                   print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
                   guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
                   DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                   }
               }
           }
    
    extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
            
            let application = UIApplication.shared
            
            if(application.applicationState == .active){
                print("user tapped the notification bar when the app is in foreground")
                
            }
            
            if(application.applicationState == .inactive)
            {
                print("user tapped the notification bar when the app is in background")
            }
            
            guard let rootViewController = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController else {
                return
            } 
// Do some work 


            completionHandler()
        }
    }
```

But this was not the case. Nothing were printed out in the logs. Is there another way to know when the app (in the background or terminated) is launched or openend by accepting a SharePlay request ?

Comment: did u get it running?

Comment: @KirtiParghi Yes, I did. My approach is shown below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if one accepts the SharePlay request, one will join a session. After that you can switch to a specific ViewController. You can call this function for example in

```
func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {

    if #available(iOS 15, *) {
        let _ = CoordinationManager.shared
    }
}
```

and the CoordinationManager could look like this

```
    class CoordinationManager {
        
        static let shared = CoordinationManager()
        
        private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
        
        // Published values that the player, and other UI items, observe
        @Published var groupSession: GroupSession<MovieWatchingActivity>?
        @Published var enquedMovie: Movies?
        
        private init() {
            
            Task {
                // await new sessions to watch movies together
                for await groupSession in MovieWatchingActivity.sessions() {
                    
                    //set the app's active group session
                    self.groupSession = groupSession
                    
                    //remove previous subscriptions
                    subscriptions.removeAll()
                    
                    //observe changes to the session state
                    groupSession.$state.sink { [weak self] state in
                        if case .invalidated = state {
                            // set the groupSession to nil to publish
                            // the invalidated session state
                            self?.groupSession = nil
                            self?.subscriptions.removeAll()
                        }
                    }.store(in: &subscriptions)
                    
                    // join the session to participate in playback coordination
                    groupSession.join()
                    
                    // navigate user to correct view controller to show videos
                    guard let windowScene = await UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
                          let sceneDelegate = await windowScene.delegate as? SceneDelegate,
                          let navigationController = await sceneDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController else {
                              return
                          }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        navigationController.pushViewController(GroupMovieController(), animated: true)
                    }
                    
                    // observe when the local user or a remote participant starts an activity
                    groupSession.$activity.sink { [weak self] activity in
                        // set the movie to enqueue it in the player
                        self?.enquedMovie = activity.movie
                    }.store(in: &subscriptions)
                }
            }
        }
... 
}
```